# Desktop Icons and all other things grow larger

Tags: windows-11, icons, desktop

I am using my pc for coding and listening song simultaneously but suddenly my pc stop working and screen got turn off this happens frequently. But when I tried to pause the song and got no response I press alt+f4 several times and after a minute I restarted my pc. After restarting, my pc's icon and all font and everything got bigger and I have no idea what to do. I restart my pc few times but this thing won't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxD0w.jpg)

For reference I add pictures of my desktop I use win 11 pro as os.
Amd ryzen 5 5600g
32 gb ram
Msi 450b mortar max mobo
Please help me!!!!

Comment: This larger icon issue is not only in desktop but also every app i open. Every thing got bigger and this is very irritating and problematic for me

Comment: Is system restore enabled? If so, do you have any restore point to revert to just in that case?

Comment: No my system didn't have any restore point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start by checking your display preferences for font or icon size. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-display-settings-in-windows-37f0e05e-98a9-474c-317a-e85422daa8bb#WindowsVersion=Windows_11 . The same way they can be set by adjusting here, it can also be adjusted by holding the control key and moving forwards or backwards with your mouse wheel.

Comment: Note that Ctrl-Mouse Wheel changes desktop icon size, but does **not** affect scaling. Within most applications, though, it's a convenient way to zoom a pane, including text and images.

Comment: this thing doesnt work at all. I tried several times

Comment: I later reinstalled amd adrenaline graphics driver and everything worked fine. I think yesterday my graphics driver crashed due to some reason.